# Question about putting a fixed button in a static tableviewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I made a scrollable screen with a static tableview.

[image]

But I want to create a UIButton that is independent of scrolling this table view.

I want to anchor it to the bottom of the view as shown below.

[image]

Is it possible to dock a button like that at the bottom of the screen in a scrollable static tableview?

Answer (score 1):

**You should create a footer view for `tableView` to do this.**

***Programmatically***

```swift
let footerView = UIView()
footerView.backgroundColor = .red // your color
// You have to give height and width yourself
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
button.setTitle("<title>", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
footerView.addSubview(button)
```

---

***via Interface Builder***

Simply you should drag and drop `UIView` (`CMD + Shift + L` > type uiview) to your tableView and then add a button to your `footerView`, set constraints.

---

**Then you should add this `footerView` to your `tableView`**

```swift
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

---

**Create an action for your button**

```swift
@objc func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("didTapButton called")
}
```